# How to use OpenStreetMap tiles on android with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, openstreetmap, react-native-maps

I was currently trying to add a OSM (OpenStreetMap) to my android application which is built with react native. However it still shows the Google Map with react-native-maps

This is my code

```
<View>
      <MapView style={styles.map}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 37.78825,
          longitude: -122.4324,
          latitudeDelta: 12,
          longitudeDelta: 12,
        }}
        rotateEnabled={false}
        zoomEnabled={false}>
        <UrlTile
          urlTemplate="https://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          shouldReplaceMapContent={true}
          maximumZ={19}
          flipY={false}
        />
      </MapView>
    </View>
```

Does anybody could help me to show the OSM on Android App with react native?

Additionally, the package.json is

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/html-elements": "latest",
    "@gluestack-style/react": "latest",
    "@gluestack-ui/themed": "latest",
    "@legendapp/motion": "latest",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^3.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.14",
    "expo-font": "^11.6.0",
    "expo-location": "^16.3.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "npm": "^10.1.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-maps": "1.7.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.10.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.25.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0"
  },
```